# Alter statement datatype update taking long time

Tags: oracle

i have tried to update the datatype from BYTE to CHAR instantly all columns(Around 100+ columns) updated.
but when i tried to rollback CHAR to BYTE its slowly loading for particular table which has around 87 million records.

right now my idea is to create one temp table and copy the data to temp table and drop that original table and recreate with updated datatype.it is good because copying to temp table millions of records takes long time for multiple table that im going to do.

any suggestion?

Comment: If you have the possibility to go *off-line* and you have approx. *twice* the space than copy the data with `CTAS` will be much better than to modify in-place.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber CTAS wont copy exact table column length and table has index and partition's

Comment: For sure, this must be considered if you make `DIY` reorganisation. You may also check the `DBMS_REDEFINITION` making it easier and also *online*.

Answer (score 0):

Converting from byte to char is "instaneous" because we in effect increasing the size of the column.  Converting back is (potentially) a reduction and hence we need to check the existing data.

However, most likely we're not really changing the data, we're just checking it - so you can see that by checking the redo before and after such an operation.  Here's on a 25million row table

```
 SID_STAT# NAME                                                                                  VALUE
---------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
       313 redo size                                                                        5580874020

SQL>   alter table t modify c1   varchar2(100 byte);

Table altered.

 SID_STAT# NAME                                                                                  VALUE
---------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
       313 redo size                                                                        5580877992
```

If you can't afford to take the time (that the table is locked) then as has been suggested, dbms_redefinition here probably will help, but don't forget - this will *move all* of the data.

```
SQL> desc t
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 PK                                                 NUMBER(38)
 C1                                                 VARCHAR2(100 CHAR)
 C2                                                 VARCHAR2(100 CHAR)
 C3                                                 VARCHAR2(100 CHAR)
 C4                                                 VARCHAR2(100 CHAR)
 C5                                                 VARCHAR2(100 CHAR)
 C6                                                 VARCHAR2(100 CHAR)
 C7                                                 VARCHAR2(100 CHAR)

SQL> create table t1 (
  2    pk int,
  3    c1 varchar2(100 byte),
  4    c2 varchar2(100 byte),
  5    c3 varchar2(100 byte),
  6    c4 varchar2(100 byte),
  7    c5 varchar2(100 byte),
  8    c6 varchar2(100 byte),
  9    c7 varchar2(100 byte)
 10  )
 11  tablespace largetmp;

Table created.

SQL> exec dbms_redefinition.start_redef_table(user, 'T', 'T1');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    l_err pls_integer;
  3  begin
  4    dbms_redefinition.copy_table_dependents(
  5      uname             => user,
  6      orig_table        => 'T',
  7      int_table         => 'T1',
  8      num_errors        => l_err);
  9    dbms_output.put_line('l_err=' || l_err);
 10  end;
 11  /
l_err=0

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> exec dbms_redefinition.finish_redef_table(user, 'T', 'T1');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>

SQL> desc t
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- --------------
 PK                                        NOT NULL NUMBER(38)
 C1                                                 VARCHAR2(100)
 C2                                                 VARCHAR2(100)
 C3                                                 VARCHAR2(100)
 C4                                                 VARCHAR2(100)
 C5                                                 VARCHAR2(100)
 C6                                                 VARCHAR2(100)
 C7                                                 VARCHAR2(100)
```